# Problems with pagination links and routs with version 6 of node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am making a board gaming app and when I aztualized it with the last version of node , the links and routs stopped working. I saw an example here with the last version but it didn't work and search but I found examples of pagination with older versions. Can anybody told me what am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

```
import "./App.css";
//import { getAllCategories } from "./utils/api.js";
// import { getUsername } from "./utils/api.js";
//import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Home } from "./pages/home/home.js";
import { Reviews } from "./pages/review.js";
import { About } from "./pages/aboutUs";
import { Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";
import { StyledLink } from "./styles";

function App() {
  return (
    <section className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <StyledLink to="/">Home</StyledLink>
          <StyledLink to="/aboutUs">About us</StyledLink>
          <StyledLink to="/review">Review</StyledLink>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="aboutUs" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="review" elemnent={<Reviews />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </section>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The error that I see in the console is :

bundle.js:40315 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')

The above error occurred in the  component:

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says:

> BrowserRouter A that uses the HTML5 history API (pushState,
> replaceState and the popstate event) to keep your UI in sync with the
> URL.

Source: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter

> Router The common low-level interface for all router components.
> Typically apps will use one of the high-level routers instead:
> BrowserRouter, HashRouter, MemoryRouter, NativeRouter, StaticRouter

Source: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Router

```
import "./App.css";
//import { getAllCategories } from "./utils/api.js";
// import { getUsername } from "./utils/api.js";
//import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Home } from "./pages/home/home.js";
import { Reviews } from "./pages/review.js";
import { About } from "./pages/aboutUs";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";
import { StyledLink } from "./styles";

function App() {
  return (
    <section className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <StyledLink to="/">Home</StyledLink>
          <StyledLink to="/aboutUs">About us</StyledLink>
          <StyledLink to="/review">Review</StyledLink>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="aboutUs" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="review" elemnent={<Reviews />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </section>
  );
}

export default App;
```